# how to know print size after page break

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, iframe-resizer

I use iframe and height fit use [iframeResizer](http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/) and iframe cotent height is variable.

Problem is that print page content is cutting because i fix iframe height use iframeResizer but page break make diff iframe content height.

then I have some questions.

1. how to know height after page break? I try to solve problem get height and change iframe height but don't know.
2. how to solve that?
3. when page break working? I check `window.onbeforeprint` use iframeResize but not change height.